# Allow people to connect to my IP address to view content?

Tags: apache

I'm using XAMPP to test pages on my local machine and I'd like people to be able to see my content by connecting to my IP address (eg. in browser they would put 1.1.1.1/index.php in the address bar to see my localhost/index.php). My firewall is off, according to XAMPP Apache services seem to be running perfectly. Even if I try WAMP or UniformServer I can't seem to allow people to connect to me. Ports as far as I know have been forwarded correctly.

I'm ripping my hair over this, I can't seem to get this to work.

edit; I should probably mention I'm under W7 x86-64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this article](http://lifehacker.com/124212/geek-to-live--how-to-set-up-a-personal-home-web-server) (this guide is more user-friendly compared with Apache docs) which explains how to install and configure Apache on a Windows machine (you can skip step-3 which is irrelevant to your needs) and how to make it accessible via your external IP

Comment: While not the answer that solved my problem (it turns out my wireless adapter's settings wasn't configured properly), this article was very user friendly and gave me some helpful tips on how to share a specific folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the apache httpdocs:

Listen (your ip):8000

[Here is the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html)